# How do you add a lookup field to a dataset?

Tags: delphi, dataset, lookup

I've got a dataset that I need a lookup field for.  Problem is, this dataset's structure is defined by the result of a query.  I can't add the field as a TFieldDef before setting `.Active = true;` because it gets overwritten, and I can't add it *after* running the query because you can't alter the structure of an open dataset.

There has to be some way to do this.  Does anyone know how?

EDIT:  There seems to be some confusion about what I'm looking for. I'm not looking for a lookup at query time. I'm looking for a **lookup field**, a TField object where FieldKind = fkLookup, so that it can be used with a data-aware lookup combo box, for editing the data after the query has returned its result. This has nothing whatsoever to do with the SQL and everything to do with Delphi's dataset model and data-aware controls.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to define persistent fields at design time.

You could also modify your SQL statement to get the calculated values from the server.

Comment: I need something that can be modified at runtime, via a lookup column in a grid control, and that specifically requires a lookup field in the dataset.

Comment: The question was about calculated fields, not lookup fields.
I'm not sure if I understand your problem but you could also define persistent fields in code, at runtime, before opening the dataset. In other words, have the FieldDefs created by your code, not automatically by the dataset. There you can define calculated or lookup fields, too.

Comment: I wonder if you edited the question or I was hallucinating. ;-) I thought the question was about calculated fields.

Comment: @TOndrej: He edited the question, after sighing at my response. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the fields yourself before you open the dataset.

First get all your field definitions from the database

```
  DataSet.FieldDefs.Update;
```

Then loop through each fielddef and create the normal field, and also create the lookup field where appropriate. Simplified version of the code like this;

```
  for I := 0 to DataSet.FieldDefs.Count - 1 do
  begin
    // Allocate a normal field
    AField := DataSet.FieldDefs[I].CreateField(DataSet);

    // Add lookup field if we have another table to look it up from
    if (??? this is the key field of a lookup table) then
    begin
      AField := TStringField.Create(DataSet.Owner);
      AField.FieldName := ???;
      AField.DataSet := DataSet;
      AField.FieldKind := fkLookup;
      AField.KeyFields := ???;
      AField.LookupKeyFields := ???;
      AField.LookupDataSet := ???;
      AField.LookupResultField := ???;
    end;
  end;
```

Then you can open the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You have two datasets on your form (say **tblOrder**,**tblCustomer**)
One field in the order is a foreign key to the customer table **customerId** 
The Key field of the customer table is **Id**, Name = **Name**

Add all fields (right click on the datasets, fields editor , add all fields.

Then right click on the order table and choose fields editor then right click **new field**.

Name = myLookup,Type is string,Size is xx, **FieldType = Lookup**.
**Key field = customerid,dataset = tblCustomer, lookup Key = Id,Result field = Name**.


Now your lookup field is defined.
To make it work in an editor (say in a TDBLookupCombo)
Add a datasources to the form **dsOrder**
Connect it to tblOrder.

Now set datasource = dsOrder,Field = myLookup
You don't have to set the lookup source...

Answer (score -1):

Let you have table `Orders` with field (among others) `CustomerId` (of type `Integer`), and table `Customers` with fields `CustomerId` (of type `Integer`) and `CustomerName` (of type `String`). Then, in Delphi IDE,  drop on the form datasets `table_main` and `table_lookup` (for tables `Orders` and `Customers` respectively). Open fields editor for `table_main`, add (among others) field `CustomerId`, then create new field with field properties:

> name: CustomerName (for example)
>
> type: integer
>
> field type: lookup

and with lookup properties:

> dataset: table_lookup
>
> Key fields: CustomerId
>
> Lookup Keys: CustomerId
>
> Result Fields: CustomerName

Hope it is still relevant now.